# How to make Spork load locales and factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, automated-tests, spork, guard

So on a Rails 3.0.9 app I'm using Spork/Guard/RSpec/FactoryGirl on 1.9.2.

I would like to know how can I get Spork/Guard to automatically update my factories and locales.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for locales, just put `I18n.reload!` into Spork's `each_run` section in `spec/spec_helper.rb`.
It should work.

Answer (score 6):

In your Gemfile

```
gem "factory_girl_rails", :require => false
```

And then in spec/spec_helper.rb

```
Spork.each_run do
  require 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

That should work